# Remove extra space right of Kendo menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

How to remove extra space of Kendo menu item displaying at end.

Here is an image of my menu:

[image: Kendo Menu]

In the above menu after Events it is displaying an extra blank. Is there any way to hide or remove it?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I've taken from here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/7bk2h/1/ and also I tried below link http://www.telerik.com/forums/that-space-to-the-right-of-the-last-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following CSS style:

```
#menu {
    float: left;
}
```

Where `menu` is the `id` of the HTML element containing the menu.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/7bk2h/16/

Comment: I want to display my menu at center of the page (horizontal align center).

Comment: I got it, I put this thing in div and applied my style. Thanks OnaBai